# Powershell Script Connect to Exchange OnPrem - Import-Pssession: Access Denied

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a main Powershell Script that needs to do multiple Changes to users.
Among other things it also runs another script which connects to the Exchange Server and changes the LitigationHold of the user.

When I run the main script interactively with the same user this works just fine.
But when I try to run it from a scheduled task I get the following error:

> Import-PSSession : Running the Get-Command command in a remote session
> reported the following error: WIN32 internal erroor "Acess is denied"
> 0x5 occured while reading the console output buffer.

This is the main script:

```
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $SamAccountName,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    $UserPrincipalName
    )
    
    $errorLog = "C:\temp\CreateNewUser_$(get-date -Format "ddMMyy_hhmmss").log"
    
    cd 'C:\ProgramData\protected-networks.com\8MAN\scripts\analyze'
    #& '.\CreateHomeDirectory.ps1' $SamAccountName
    & '.\SetLitigation.ps1' $UserPrincipalName
```

And this is the SetLitigationscript that gives the errors:

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0)]
[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
$UserPrincipalName
)

sleep 60 

$errorLog = "C:\temp\SetLitigation_$(get-date -Format "ddMMyy_hhmmss").log"

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://dg-ex-02.dg.test/PowerShell/ 

Import-PSSession $Session -AllowClobber |log $errorLog

Sleep 60
set-mailbox $UserPrincipalName -litigationHoldEnabled $true |log $errorLog
sleep 60
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

Why does this scripts generate errors when run from a scheduled task?

Comment: `|log $errorLog`. Where is function `log` defined? Why use variable `$errorlog` when this is not also passed as parameter?

Comment: Hi Theo thank you for your question.
I didn't copy the whole Script, the log function is defined in the script but the problem is not about the log function

Comment: Found a solution to this access denied problem?